# storeValue in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium

Need to store check box value in a variable and if it is "on" i need to call a function else call a different function.

Comment: I tried with gotoif prototype, but it is supporting for "storetextpresent" but not "stored values"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Flow Control extension/plugin and the `storeChecked` command.

See following example:

```
<tr>
  <td>storeChecked</td>
  <td>id=myCheckbox</td>
  <td>isChecked</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>gotoIf</td>
  <td>${isChecked} == true</td>
  <td>isChecked</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>echo</td>
  <td>Checkbox is NOT checked</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>goto</td>
  <td>done</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>label</td>
  <td>isChecked</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>echo</td>
  <td>Checkbox is checked</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>label</td>
  <td>done</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>echo</td>
  <td>Done!</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following blog post details how you can skip rows after a failed test (e.g. is check box checked) and then resume at a later point. You could have two of these, one for checked, the other for unchecked.

The example given is:

```
|Skip Subsequent Rows If A Step Fails|  
|Do Something|Funny|  
|Check|Is|Everyone|Laughing|true|  
|Do Something|Hilarious|  
|Check|Is|Everyone|Laughing|true|  
|Do Something|Mean|  
|Check|Is|Everyone|Laughing|true|  
|This row would be skipped|  
|So would this one|  
|Resume|  
|This row will be executed now|  
|And so on...|
```

**Controlling test flow in FitNesse (making it stop running rows)**

http://theroamingcoder.com/node/3